# How to configure mongo trigger for dev and prod cluster using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**How to configure mongo trigger for dev and prod cluster using Nodejs ?**

I have some query regarding mongodb trigger.
I have 2 cluster - ( DEV and PROD )
I want to create 2 trigger 1 for dev and 1 for prod.
By default - I see Dev and Prod are getting selected under link data source, and it is disable I am not able to uncheck it.

[image]

I know I can remove linked data source from ---
App service ---> Triggers ---> Manage triggers.

[image]

But this is not the solution. Please help me. Do I need to create all together diff account for DEV and Prod ? I don't think so it is the feasible solution.

I am pulling the data from 1 collection and inserting to another collections.

What is happening now - Pull the data from dev - but it is inserting to prod and dev both cluster. Because both are tagged to it.

More details Here is the code -

```
// register activity

exports = async function(changeEvent) {
    try {
      const sourceDatabase = "Abcd"; // Source database
      const targetDatabase = "Abcd"; // Target database
      const targetCollectionName = "activities"; // Target collection name
    
      // Get references to the MongoDB collections in both databases
      const sourceCollection = context.services.get(sourceDatabase).db(changeEvent.ns.db).collection(changeEvent.ns.coll);
      const targetDB = context.services.get(targetDatabase).db(targetDatabase);
    
      if (changeEvent.operationType === "insert") {
        // Insert event: replicate the user document to the Activity collection
        const userDocument = changeEvent.fullDocument;
        console.log("User Document:", JSON.stringify(userDocument));
        if (userDocument.custom && userDocument.custom.role === "customer") {
            // Transform the user data to match the Activity schema
            const activityData = {
              user: userDocument._id, // Reference to the User
              userId: userDocument.sub,
              email: userDocument.email,
              activities: {
                premiumPlan: false,
                firstVideoWatched: false,
                currentVideo_3days_WatchStreak: 0, // Updated field name
                longestVideo_7days_WatchStreak: 0, // Updated field name
                animalExpertCount: 0,
                categoryExperts: [],
              },
            };
            
            try {
              const targetCollection = targetDB.collection(targetCollectionName);
            
              // Insert the transformed data into the Activity collection
              targetCollection.insertOne(activityData);
            } catch(err) {
              console.log("error performing mongodb write: ", JSON.stringify(err));
            }
            
        }
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("error performing mongodb write: ", err.message);
    }
  };
```

Comment: it lets you select cluster name below doesnt it. the top just shows the available clusters u can select below. u should be able to create 2 triggers for the 2 clusters seperately

Comment: @cmgchess - I am pulling the data from 1 collection and inserting to another collections. 

What is happening now - Pull the data from dev - but it is inserting to prod and dev both cluster. Because both are tagged to it.

Comment: @cmgchess - I don't think so you understood the question properly.